# Is STL Vector calling a destructor of a not-allocated object?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

The folowing code shows an output not expected:

```
class test
{
    public:
    test()
    {
        std::cout << "Created" << (long)this << std::endl;
    }
    ~test()
    {
        std::cout << "Destroyed" << (long)this << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<test> v;
    test t;
    v.push_back(t);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When executed it shows:

```
Created-1077942161
Destroyed-1077942161
Destroyed674242816
```

I think the second "Destroyed" output should not be there. When I don't use the vector the result is one Created and one Destroyed line as expected. Is this behavior normal?

(This is compiled with GCC on a FreeBSD system)

Comment: +1 for the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: To print pointers it's best to cast to void pointer: `std::cout << (void*)this << std::endl;`.

Comment: Also returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` is optional. You can omit the return value in `main`, it will return `0` (which will turn into whichever number means "normal termination" for your platform)

Comment: This is fine. The compiler provided `test(const test&);` is being called.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Everything is as it should be: there's the local variable `t`, which gets created and then destroyed at the end of `main()`, and there's `v[0]`, which gets created and destroyed at the end of `main()`.

You don't see the creation of `v[0]` because that happens by copy or move constructor, which your test class doesn't provide. (So the compiler provides one for you, but without output.)

---

For testing purposes it's handy to write for yourself once and for all a test class that contains all the possible constructors, destructors, assignment and swap operators and prints a diagnostic line in each, so you can witness how objects behave when used in containers and algorithms.

Comment: It cannot be `move constructor`.

Comment: @Namaz: Right. To use the move constructor, you'd have to say eitehr `v.push_back(std::move(t))`, or `v.push_back(test())`. Both would create a similar sequence of messages, though.

Answer (score 29):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class test
{
    public:
    test()
    {
        std::cout << "Created " << (long)this << std::endl;
    }
    test( const test& )
    {
        std::cout << "Copied " << (long)this << std::endl;
    }
    ~test()
    {
        std::cout << "Destroyed " << (long)this << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<test> v;
    test t;
    v.push_back(t);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

> **Output:**

```
Created -1076546929
Copied 147865608
Destroyed -1076546929
Destroyed 147865608
```

`std::vector::push_back` copies the `t` object, you can see the copy constructor being invoked by the above code.

Answer (score 2):

The vector is holding a copy of `t`, therefore after the call to `push_back`, you have two versions of `t` ... one on the stack, and one in the vector.  Since the vector version was created by a copy-construtor, you don't see a "Created ..." prompt for that object ... but it still must be destroyed when the vector container goes out of scope, therefore you get two "Destroyed ..." messages.